# How do I check if a given cell contains any number?

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, count

I tried with `=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B3))>0`, as shown here https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/if-cell-contains-any-number/,
but it doesn't work I get an error in return.
I just want to check if a cell contains any numeric character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&""; "\d+"))
```

[image]

Comment: Using this formula I just get a "#REF!" error stating that it can't overwrite over the next cell, even if I delete them beforehand so that they are empty.

Comment: @Dravis800 if you are using this formula: =INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&""; "\d+")) make sure you delete everything in range A2:A... only then you can deploy this formula which will auto-calculate for every row. also... this formula is meant to be placed in row 2

Comment: You are right it was an issue of the range not being empty, now this also works :)

Answer (score 1):

`RegexMatch()` will do that. Try-

```
=IF(RegExMatch(TEXT(A1,"@"),"[0-9]"),"Has Number","Text Only")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but this still gives me an error, however I tried with "=REGEXMATCH(TESTO(A2;"@"); "[0-9]+")" and it works; I'm seriously worried at why your formula works for you but not for me, I'm using google sheets btw (a user removed it from the title of my question cause it's already in the tag of the question and so is redundant) However it also returns TRUE when the cell is empty which I guess I can work with anyway.

Comment: The error your formula gives me is "Formula parse error". 

The "TESTO" part in the formula I'm using corresponds to "TEXTJOIN" in english

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the count/find formula does work if array-entered:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2))>0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but this still gives me an error, however I tried with "=REGEXMATCH(TESTO(A2;"@"); "[0-9]+")" and it works;
I'm seriously worried at why your formula works for you but not for me, I'm using google sheets btw (a user removed it from the title of my question cause it's already in the tag of the question and so is redundant)
However it also returns TRUE when the cell is empty which I guess I can work with anyway.

Comment: The error your formula gives me is "Formula parse error" btw

Comment: I thin it is a locale issue - would you like to try =ArrayFormula(COUNT(FIND({0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9};A2))>0)

Comment: The new one you sent me works, good find!